# Как сделать фон раздельно html и body?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фон раздельно html и body? `height: 100%;` чета не работает! Работает только через `float: left;` но мне нужно `margin: auto;`. Смотрите код На всю страницу!

```css
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px 0;
    font-family: tahoma;
    background: #F9F9F9;
    color: #777;
}
body {
    width: 1030px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #CCC;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
    color: #777;
}
input {
    outline: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
button {
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #8031FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d23e5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.header {
    width: 1020px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #8031FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d23e5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
main {
    width: 1020px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #2e4aa3;
}
aside {
    width: 210px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
section {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}
#column {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #8031FF;
    border: 1px solid #6d23e5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#block {
    width: 190px;
    height: 280px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #8031FF;
    border: 1px solid #6d23e5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: #8031FF;
    border-top: 1px solid #6d23e5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
            </div>
        </header>
                <main>
            <aside>
                <div id="column"></div>
                <div id="column"></div>
            </aside>
            <section>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
                <div id="block"></div>
            </section>
            <aside>
                <div id="column"></div>
                <div id="column"></div>
            </aside>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убери у `html` и `body` `height: 100%`.
Добавь:

```
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Vasso Спасибо!!

Answer (score -2):

`html` не нужно пытаться использовать как блок. Это семантический тег.

Внутрь `body` добавьте `div` и перенесите CSS из `body` в новый `div`, а из `html` - в `body`.